# Dealing with transposed data in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have some functions like this:

```
myf = function(x) {
    # many similar statements involving indexing x
    do1(x[, indexfunc1()])
    do2(x[, indexfunc1()])
    do3(x[, indexfunc1()])
    do4(x[, indexfunc1()])
    do5(x[, indexfunc1()]) 
}
```

In all these functions, I need extract columns or rows 
of x, and these functions are used in some loops.
The problem is sometimes we also have data in a transposed
format, so this means for these data we have to get t(x).
This is very ineffecient and very time consuming since 
these matrices are often huge.

Is there a smart way to deal with this? It would be very annoying 
to have to change code manually.

Comment: Can't u just solve it with apply() function !? so if its transposed use apply on the rows/columns depending on you're data !?

Comment: I'd be very surpirsed if calls to `t` are the slow part of your analysis.  Have you done any performance profiling?

Comment: @RichieCotton It takes 2 seconds to transpose the whole matrix. Imagine doing this in a for loop! Also sometimes we use the bigmemory package to store data on harddisk, in that case it's not possible to transpose at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, if your `doX` functions expect the transpose of the matrix, you are going to be calling `t` somewhere, for example

```
do1(t(x[indexfunc(),])))
```

So your options are:

1. Transpose `x` once at the top
2. Transpose at each `doX` call
3. Rewrite your `doX` functions so they take an optional `isTranspose` argument.

Option 3 will be the most work, but also the most efficient.  The situation where it would make sense to use option 2 is if `x` is huge, but you are only selecting a small number of rows/cols each time.  In which case you could do something like this:

```
matrixSelect<-function(x,subset,dim=1){
  if(dim==1)
      t(x[subset,])
  else
      x[,subset]
}
```

and then write

```
myf = function(x,dim=2) {
    # many similar statements involving indexing x
    do1(matrixSelect(x,indexfunc1(),dim)
    # etc
}
```